# How to change the license admin details via command line in clearcase?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I would like to change the license admin details to point to new single server say Iea80043 and use the port number 29005

I was searching the command line argument for it but it was different.

The example command says.

`run licadmin.exe -s27000@servername` , whether that -s27000 is port number 27000?

Should i use command like this for my scenario?

```
run licadmin.exe -s29005@Iea80043
```

Answer (score 0):

The [IBM page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21117710) mentioning your example does also mentions the the License Admin GUI expect a server name and a port number.

So yes: `-s27000` is the port number.
You can see it in "[Specifying redundant license servers](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.licensing.doc/topics/t_config_client_commandline.htm)", where it does specify:

> 27000 is the default port number.

Depending on your locale settings, you [can see error when executing licadmin.exe](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21324805)

This program is in `C\Program Files\Rational\Common\licadmin.exe`, so make sure its parent directory is in your `%PATH%`.